# How to delete a specific line of a text file?

Tags: ruby

So, I have been browsing tall and high for a solution, but came up short. So, here is my problem:

how do I write a program, that will delete a specific line from a text file?

The information is as follows:

```
Lukas;11111111;x6 y8
John;22222222;x7 y10
Fred;44444444;x8 y15
```

The info is basically name, phone number and coordinates.

How would I be able to do delete Fred from this?

I can provide my full code if needed.

Comment: Please provide the relevant code that is processing what you want to achiveve. Explain why it doesn't work so we can help you with that.

Comment: [Ruby file](http://www.filedropper.com/exam2_2) Here is the whole ruby file. I am receiveing errors on lines 67, 66 and 65. The error on line 67 is "in `block (2 levels) in <main>': undefined local variable or method `input' for main:Object (NameError)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this is simple:

1. read the file into an array
2. remove the lines you want
3. Write the content to a file (preferably a new one)

   ```
   #! /usr/bin/env ruby

   src='/tmp/data.src'
   dst='/tmp/data.new'

   content = File.readlines src
   content = content.grep_v /Fred;/
   File.open(dst,'w+') {|f| f.puts content}
   ```

Comment: I assume this will delete only Fred? Or will it allow me to pick any person?

Comment: Lucas, you could put this in a method that has an argument `name` then change the second line to `content = content.grep_v /#{name};/`.